# Fire different functions depending on checkbox state in Vue2

Tags: javascript, events, vuejs2

I'd like to know is there any way to fire custom functions - one function when checkbox changes to true value and another when it changes to false value (without using $watch).

For example:
I have input wrapped in root div

```
<div id="root">
   <input type="checkbox" v-model="editModeOn">
</div>
```

and a vue instance with disableEditMode (on checkbox unchecked) and enableEditMode (on checkbox checked)

```
new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    props: {
        editModeOn: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        disableEditMode() {
            // some code
        },
        enableEditMode() {
            // some code
        }
    },
});
```

How can I achieve this functionality? Thanks!

Comment: Is this really a component? Root Vue's do not generally have `props`. Also, if it *is* a component, will the value change from outside the component resulting in you needing to handle the change?

Comment: Yes, it's a real component and it can has props if they declared that way (you can try it). That was made to specify type of editModeOn prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the change event.

```
@change="editModeOn ? enableEditMode() : disableEditMode()"
```

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data:{
        editModeOn: false
    },
    methods: {
        disableEditMode() {
           console.log("disable")
        },
        enableEditMode() {
            console.log("enable")
        }
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="root">
   <input type="checkbox" v-model="editModeOn" @change="editModeOn ? enableEditMode() : disableEditMode()">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's great solution. But maybe it's better to use @change (for example if for some reasons input will be disabled)

Comment: @bashkovpd I was just thinking the same.